# Prove that if the product of two formal power series $A$ and $B$ is $0$ then $A = 0$ or $B = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series

We know that if you are multiplying fps $A$ by a fps $B$, the product can be written as:
$$AB = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^ia_jb_{i-j}\right)X^i$$

or $$a_0b_0 + (a_0b_1 + a_1b_0)x + (a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0)x^2 + \ldots$$

so each of $(a_0b_0), (a_0b_1 + a_1b_0), (a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0), \ldots$ must equal $0$.

The only way for this to happen is if $a_n = 0$,  for all n or $b_n = 0$,  for all $n$.

How do I prove this? Induction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume neither $A=0$ nor $B=0$. Let $n$ be minimal with $a_n\ne 0$, let $m$ be minimal with $b_m\ne 0$. Then the coefficient of $x^{n+m}$ in the Cauchy product equals $a_nb_m\ne 0$.

Comment: But that doesn't prove that only one of A **or** B has to be 0.

This is just a contradiction for when both A and B are non-zero. 
How do we know that both A and B don't have to be zero based on your proof?

Comment: Also, what does it mean when you say "let n be minimal"?

Comment: @bob the negation of "A or B is zero" is "neither A nor B is zero."  Hagen's proof is correct. Remember that the logical or is not one or the other, it's **inclusive** i.e. "A or B" means "A or B or both" not "A or B but not both."

Comment: Thank you @AdamHughes ! What about my second question?

Comment: @bob it's exactly as Hagen says, "minimal such that [...] is not zero." Since neither $A$ nor $B$ is zero, there must be a smallest coefficient which is non-zero, Hagen is selecting that particular one from each of the series.

Comment: @AdamHughes Why do we need the smallest one?

Comment: @bob everything else gives a sum. A sum being zero is useless since, for example $x+y=0$ just means $x=-y$, not $x=0$ or $y=0$. However a simple product being zero **does** carry the appropriate implication.